# How could I know the file on my local computer is modified or not using linux terminal?

Tags: linux

I am trying to get the information about the file modification on my local drive.
There are two files in one directory whether one is modified or both the files are modified I dont know ?

I wanted to know is there any way to get this?

I used 
ls -lrt

It gives me the time information i.e. last modified time but i need change in size info as well

please help

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a backup of those files prior to the time stamp that you already figured out, you can't.  If you do have a backup you can compare the results of

```
echo $(( ` du -b file` - `du -b file2`))
```

... or if they are text based files, you can *see* what changed using

```
diff -urp file1 file2
```

Comment: And if you don't have a backup, now is a good time to start making regular backups.